# How to convert toggle function to module pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a new javascript, i have heard that declaring global variables it's pretty much bad idea in javascript, we have to less or avoid as much as we can.

I have found page https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals and i saw module pattern it seems a good way to go.

So, i've been practicing about toggle function my first code it works fine

```js
function toggle() {
    var mainTopics = document.querySelector("#maintopics");  // target the li

    mainTopics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {     // passed "e" to get the event
        e.preventDefault();                                // prevent anchor to navigate
        mainTopics.classList.toggle("show");                // changed to toggle for the
        // the purpose of this demo
    });
}

toggle();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#maintopics.show #subtopics { 
    display: block;
}

#subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li id="maintopics"><a href="">Topics</a>
                <div id="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed code javascript to module pattern.However it didn't work, im not sure if my code is wrong or there is some important rule that i don't know.

If anyone would like to give me some advices i will appreciate it thank you very much.

```
var toggle = (function() {
  var mainTopics = document.getElementById("maintopics");

  mainTopics.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mainTopics.classList.toggle("show");
  });

  return {
    toggle()
  }
})();
```

Hi, everyone i suddenly found the solution for my case. i just need to specific the function that i want to return to object again for example in my case return toggle function it would be toggle: toggle()

```
var toggle = (function () {
var mainTopics = document.getElementById("maintopics");

mainTopics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mainTopics.classList.toggle("show");
});

return {
    toggle: toggle()
}
})();
```

Comment: What you had initially was totally fine.

Comment: So, why can't i use module pattern the second one ? is there any wrong with it ? @JordanS

Comment: Well.. it has some bugs which is why it's not working, but all you have is a single function that doesn't reference any variables outside of itself (except for the DOM), so by it's own nature it is modular.

Comment: It just isn't even valid syntax `return { toggle() }` isn't a thing. Not sure what you are trying to do with that line.

Comment: The reason for the immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) you may see in a lot of javascript modules is to create a private scope for variables so they don't pollute the global scope. However, in your second example, you are setting `toggle` equal to the return value of an IIFE, that is to say, you are calling the function rather than assigning it to a variable. Also, there is a syntax error as someone else pointed out.

Comment: One way you could make your initial function more modular is instead of `var mainTopics = document.getElementById("maintopics");`, pass the DOM element into the function and get the element outside of the function call. But once again, this is a really simple case and it's totally fine as is.

Comment: @Damon thanks, that's why i asked a question here because i really don't know what bug is there. I know there is something i don't understand.

Comment: @JordanS thanks for an advice, But i still don't undertstand how to do it as what you said ?